# Problem removing entity with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

**UPDATE**

My friend did the same lines of code and his lines just worked. What could it be? I use NetBeans 7.0.1 and his is 6.9.1. My GlassFish is 3.1 and his is 3.0.1

**END OF UPDATE**

```
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Vehicle.findAll", query = "SELECT v FROM Vehicle v")})
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "color_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Color color;

public Vehicle() {
}

//Getters and Setters

}

---

@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Car.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Car c")})
public class Car extends Vehicle implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "airbag")
    private Boolean airbag;

public Car() {
}

//Getters and Setters

}
```

When I'm trying to remove a car it thorws an Exception and in the Stacktrace has a UPDATE query which is pretty weird if I'm trying to remove.

Do you guys have any idea of what might be going on here?

```
Car car = em.find(Car.class, id);
em.remove(car);
```

Stack:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'color_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: UPDATE vehicle SET color_id = ? WHERE (id = ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(br.com.something.entity.Vehicle[ id=3 ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.updateObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:749)
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you remove the Car from the DB?

Comment: I've edited right before the stacktrace

Comment: What happens is Hibernate trying to disconnect Car from Color before actually deleting the car, which explicitly violates the non-null constraint on the DB. Why this happens, I can't figure out, that's why I'm commenting and not answering :(

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need a CascadeType on the relation between car and color?

Comment: It's not it. It works fine on my buddy's computer, but mine does not.

Comment: Are you both using the same database? Do the table definitions match?

Comment: Ya, the only difference is netbeans and glassfish versions.